# Problem solving question with average

Tags: problem-solving

Johnny had to take a test a day late. His 96 raised the class average from 71 to 72. How many students, including Johnny, took the test?

I tried to do trial and error to see how many students there were but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Letting $n$ be the number of students excluding Johnny...
$$\text{Old average} = \frac{71n}{n}$$
$$\text{New average} = \frac{71n + 96}{n+1}$$

Note that $\text{New average} - \text{Old average} = 1$.

Comment: I set the equations equal to each other and I got n^2 +25n. So would the number of students be 25? Without Johnny? Because when I plug in 25 for n the equations do not equal eachother

Comment: @Layla The expressions should not be equal, but, rather, they should differ by $1$.

Comment: How do I solve for n if they need to differ by 1?

Comment: @Layla Subtract the *old average* from the *new average* and set that equal to $1$.

Comment: By subtracting I get (71n^2 + 96n - 71n^2 - 71n)/ (n(n+1) and I get 25/(n+1)??? So I set that equal to 1 and get 25=n+1? So it's 25 total students?